# How to convert List<List<String[]>> into String[][][]?

Tags: java, arrays, string, multidimensional-array

This is my code:

```
    List<List<String[]>> myBigList=new ArrayList<List<String[]>>();
    String[] s11={"A","30"};
    String[] s12={"B","20"};
    List<String[]> l1=new ArrayList<String[]>();
    l1.add(s11);
    l1.add(s12);

    String[] s21={"B","10"};
    String[] s22={"B","20"};
    List<String[]> l2=new ArrayList<String[]>();
    l2.add(s21);
    l2.add(s22);

    String[] s31={"C","2"};
    String[] s32={"A","10"};
    String[] s33={"A","3"};
    List<String[]> l3=new ArrayList<String[]>();
    l3.add(s31);
    l3.add(s32);
    l3.add(s33);

    myBigList.add(l1);
    myBigList.add(l2); 
    myBigList.add(l3);

    String[][] test2DArr=new String[2][myBigList.size()];
myBigList.toArray(test2DArr);
```

When running it say "[ERROR]  - Uncaught exception escaped"
So how to convert List> into String[][]?

Comment: First, you don't have a list of a list of `String`s, you have a list of a list of `String[]`.  There's a sizable difference with that.

Comment: The first question that should be asked is, why do you want a String[][]?

Comment: `list - 1d array`, `list in list - 2d array`, `array in list in list` - **WTF**!!

Comment: @Makoto
Thank u I fixed

Comment: What about this is "fixed"?  I see no change in the fact that you have an `ArrayList<String[]>`.  Nor do I see a justification for a switch to a `String[][]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming (it's not easy...) that anyone will ever face similar problem, the working solution to convert `List<List<String[]>>` to `String[][][]` would be:

```
// List<List<String[]>> myBigList = new ArrayList<List<String[]>>();
String[][][] amyBigArray = new String[myBigList.size()][][];
for (int i = 0; i < myBigList.size(); i++) {
    int innerSize = myBigList.get(i).size();
    String[][] innerArray = new String[innerSize][];
    for (int j = 0; j < innerSize; j++) {
        innerArray[j] = myBigList.get(i).get(j);
    }
    amyBigArray[i] = innerArray;
}
```

It can be printed with:

```
for (String[][] strings : amyBigArray) {
    for (String[] strings3 : strings) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(strings3));
    }
}
```

and it gives correct output for given in question input:

```
[A, 30]
[B, 20]
[B, 10]
[B, 20]
[C, 2]
[A, 10]
[A, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

If i understood you correctly this is what you want (more or less)

```
List<String> list = ..;
String[] array = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
```

But anyway. Your logic is completely wrong, you have "array in array in array in array array in array in array of array in array" .. you get me ?.

Comment: String[] s11={"A","30"};
          String[] s12={"B","20"};
          List<String[]> l1=new ArrayList<String[]>();
          l1.add(s11);
          l1.add(s12);
          String[][] test2DArr=new String[2][l1.size()];
          l1.toArray(test2DArr);

Comment: @Tom Edit your question with details WHAT you are trying to do (achieve) in your code, program as you didn't really explained what is that you try to do